# In C++ can a derived class (with more parameters than it's Base class) use base class functions and overloaded operators?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

Im new to c++ classes so this question may look stupid for some people, but i wonder if we can use base class functions in derived class, like we do with constructors?

As far as I know, constructors from base class can be used in derived class without copying the same lines of code again and again, just slightly modifying the constructor to fit derived class additional parameters.
For example:

```
class parent{

protected:

    char *p;

public:

    parent()
    {
        p=NULL;
    }

    parent(char ch[10])
    {
       /// initialization for p with ch (p=ch);
    }

    /// other functions and destructor ..
};

class child: public parent{

protected:
    char *c;

public:
    child():parent()
    {
        c=NULL;
    }
    child(char ch1[10], char ch2[10]): parent(ch1)
    {
       /// initialization for c with ch2 (c=ch2);
    }
};
```

I tried to do something similar but not with constructors, with parent class functions and overloaded operators , and it didn't work ( maybe i was doing something wrong):

```
class parent{
    
    protected:
    
        char *p;
    
    public:
    
        parent()
        {
            p=NULL;
        }
    
        parent(char ch[10])
        {
           /// initialization for p with ch (p=ch);
        }
        parent &operator=(const parent &p1)
        {
          /// overloading the operator for parent class parameters;
        }
    
        /// other functions and destructor ..
    };
    
    class child: public parent{
    
    protected:
        char *c;
    
    public:
        child():parent()
        {
            c=NULL;
        }
        child(char ch1[10], char ch2[10]): parent(ch1)
        {
           /// initialization for c with ch2 (c=ch2);
        }
        child &operator=(const parent &p1, const child &p2): parent &operator=(p1)
{ 
    ////didn't work
}
    };
```

and that's why im asking this question.

I mainly want to know if this is possible because it would be helpful with operator overloading( normally i need to copy-paste the code for overloading an operator, from base to derived class, and jus add a few more lines, depending on how many parameters are in derived class. But it's pretty annoying to write or copy paste the same lines of code again and again).

So is there a solution?

Comment: *"I tried to do something similar but not with constructors, with parent class functions , and it didn't work "* Then can you show us that attempt instead? We can't help identify an issue unless you share the relevant code.

Comment: And please be more precise than "didn't work". What didn't work? If you got a compiler error please show it to us.

Comment: I edited the code; The error1: 'only constructor take members initializer' and error2: 'abonament_premium& abonament_premium::operator=(const abonament&, const abonament_premium&)' must take exactly one argument|

Comment: Initialiser lists can only be used in the definition of constructors because (well) the purpose of a constructor is initialisation of an object and its component parts (i.e. based and members).    Other functions have to call the inherited version explicitly in their body.   And you can't change the basic form of the copy-assignment `operator=()` - it is always a non-static member function that accepts a single argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

The assignment operator always has to take exactly one argument. If you think about it, two arguments doesn't make sense, as there's always only one thing on the right hand side of the `=` sign:

```
child1 = child2; // child2 is passed into operator= for child1
```

Since a `const parent&` is in particular a `const child&`, this problem is easy to solve: take a single parameter of type `const child&` and use it as both the `parent` and the `child` that you want to initialize from.

The second problem is the use of the special colon syntax which is only for constructors. If you want to call the parent's assignment operator, you need to use a different syntax.

```
child &operator=(const child &p)
{
    parent::operator=(p);
    c = p.c;
}
```

In general, to call a base class member, you need to give the specific base class name (because one class can have several base classes, all of which might define the same member function), followed by two colons `::`, followed by the function name.

(As an aside, taking an array as a parameter and then storing a raw pointer in your class is probably a bad idea, as the array will go out of scope and the pointer will no longer refer to anything. It's better to use `std::string` for storage.)

Comment: *"taking an array as a parameter"*. It is not possible, there is decay, so `parent(char ch[10])` is identical to `parent(char* ch)`. There are no dangling pointers from shown code. (Advice to use `std::string` is still relevant though :-)).

Comment: That's a lot for your Answer John, that's what i was looking for ! Never thought it will be that easy. Though i think you miss a 'return *this' in operator=.